# How to achieve high TPS with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, tps

I am working on a application (Banking) which has a TPS requirement of 100 and multiple concurrent users.

Will Spring Boot 1.x.x allow me to achieve this?

Note: I would have used Spring Boot 2.x.x which supports Reactive paradigm but there is some legacy code which I have to use and it does not work on 2.x.x.

Answer (score 4):

You can hit these numbers running a Java application on any reasonable hardware. LMAX claims that [Disruptor](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) can do over [100k TPS with 1ms latency](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/LMAX). Spring Boot, or Java in general, won't be the limiting factor.

What will be the problem are the business requirements. If your application is to produce complex reports from over utilised database that's located in another data centre, well just the [packet round-trip from CA to Netherlands is 150ms](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html). If your SQL queries will take 30+ seconds, you are toast.

You can take a look at [Tuning Tomcat For A High Throughput, Fail Fast System](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/tuning-tomcat-for-a-high-throughput-fail-fast-system-e4d7b2fc163f). It gives a good insight what can be tuned in a standard Tomcat deployment (assuming you will use Tomcat in Spring Boot). However it's unlikely that HTTP connections (assuming you will expose HTTP API) will be the initial bottleneck.